# VueJS and Cordova App - Speed up dev process

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm currently developing and app with Vue (Vue ui + webpack) and Cordova.

Building the app layout and stuff is pure happiness : The vue dev environment with hot reload is really a breeze. But when I reach the parts of the app which use native phone api through Cordova plugins, here be dragons, boy. For every code line update I want to test, I need to build the Vue app through Vue UI, then build the Cordova app for the needed platform, then start it on a device or emulator.

I like to test often when I code, especially when it's about Cordova plugin which can be tricky and need a lot of customization and testing. I feel like my dev time is multiplied by 15.

Do you know a faster process to work with that environment ? (I saw the plugin cordova-hot-code-push, but deprecated).

Comment: Are you using any framework for develop hybrid apps? Now, you can use Vuejs + Ionic. Your productivity will increase.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out Decsoft app builder, it's a WYSIWYG builder based on Vue, js and bootstrap. It also generates Batch scripts to speed up the process for building across multiple platforms.